# Is there a way to skip NA values for a line plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2, linegraph

I am trying to plot 4 line graphs sharing a y axis but one of the graphs has a missing value (NA).
I want to be able to connect the two points either side of the NA value for the CI-TR graph. [image: Graphs]

Here is the data I am working with (Note CI-TR on the right hand side has the NA value)

[image: table of data]

This is my code, I have read in the table from an excel file:

```
#read the excel file (same as the table attached)
data <- read_csv("test3.csv", col_types = cols(.default = col_guess())

# gather the data for age and depth
plots <-  data %>% filter(core_id == "BKM0817") %>%
  gather(key = param, value = value, -core_id, -Age, -depth)

#this is to relabel the graph titles (NB the added a is to order alphabetically in the order I want them to appear)
plots %>%  
  mutate(facet_label = fct_recode(
    param,
    "delta ^ 13 * C[OM] ~(`\u2030 V-PDB`)" = "ad13com",
    "delta ^ 15 * N ~(`\u2030 AIR`)" = "d15N",
    "'C/N'" = "C/N",
    "CI-TR" = "aaCI-TR"
  )) %>%
          
# now plot the graphs
  ggplot(aes(y = Age, x = value)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(10720, 10568, 10620), col = "black", alpha = 0.8, lty = 2) +
  geom_lineh(colour = "black", size = 0.5) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  facet_wrap(~facet_label, scales = "free_x", labeller = label_parsed, ncol = 4) +
  scale_y_reverse(# Features of the first axis
    name = "Age (Cal. yrs BP)",

 # Add a second axis and specify its features
    sec.axis = sec_axis( trans=~./17.927, name="Depth (cm)")
  ) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Age (Cal. yrs BP)") +
theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))`
```

Comment: remove the rows with na values. `na.omit(plots)`. Since each observation is a link on the individual line you should be able to remove the point iself.

Comment: If you don't want to remove the whole row (i.e.  all values for the observation with the NA), you could impute the previous or next value for the NA that way the line should just go straight to the next *actual* measured value. OR you could impute it with the mean of the next and previous and color it to mark it as "estimate". However, this would mean that you now have "invented" values in your data/plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line geom will but cut if there are any `NA` values, so the simple solution is to remove the `NA` values from your data frame.  You can use `na.omit()` to do this, but just pay attention to *where* you use it in your code.  Your original dataset looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(pos=1:4, A=c(1.05, 2.3, 4.24, 3.89),
  B=c(4.44, NA, 2.22, 3.33))
df

>
  pos    A    B
1   1 1.05 4.44
2   2 2.30   NA
3   3 4.24 2.22
4   4 3.89 3.33
```

Plotting this after gathering you get:

```
df %>%
  gather(key=type, value=value, -pos) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=pos, y=value)) +
  geom_line(linetype=2, color='blue', size=0.7) +
  geom_point(color='red', size=3) +
  facet_wrap(~type)
```

[image]

If you used `na.omit()` on `df`, then it would remove the *entire second row*, which removes the second observation for column `A` as well.  In this case, just make sure you use `na.omit()` *after* the `gather()` function to pivot the data frame longer:

```
df %>%
  gather(key=type, value=value, -pos) %>%
  na.omit() %>%    # important this comes after the gather
  ggplot(aes(x=pos, y=value)) +
  geom_line(linetype=2, color='blue', size=0.7) +
  geom_point(color='red', size=3) +
  facet_wrap(~type)
```

[image]

In your case, the pseudo code below gives you an idea where to place `na.omit()` in your own code:

```
plots %>%
  mutate(...) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  ggplot(...) + ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the well explained answer!